# How to update table using SQL on windows visual studio

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-update

I'm trying to update a entry on my database table but I'm getting an error in my syntax, anyone know what is the fault? its not connection based and I think its purely the syntax but I could be wrong.

```
try
{
    cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE army SET(troop1 = @troop1, troop2 = @troop2, troop3 = @troop3, hero = @hero) WHERE username = ryan";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@troop1", troop1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@troop2", troop2);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@troop3", troop3);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hero", hero.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: What is the _complete_ syntax error message?

Comment: [Sql Basics Tutorial Update && Set Clause](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-update-statement.htm)

Comment: use of Parentheses is not correct but use single quotes  around ryan is nesessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax is

```
UPDATE army SET troop1 = @troop1, troop2 = @troop2, troop3 = @troop3, hero = @hero WHERE username = 'ryan'
```

- no parentheses around the `SET` list
- single quotes around the static value `'ryan'`

Comment: omg thank you, its always the small things things. I looked at the proper syntax for ages lol

Answer (score 2):

I think your

```
username = ryan
```

should be

```
username = 'ryan'
```

Looks like it is a character typed column, you need to use single quotes with it. And you don't *need* to use brackets after your `SET` part. There is no such a thing on [`UPDATE (TSQL)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx)  syntax.

By the way, don't use `AddWithValue` anymore. It *may* generate unexpected results. Use [`.Add()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or it's overloads. Read: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections and objects.

Comment: Unfortunately still getting the error its says the error is near `(troop1 = @troop1, troop2 = @troop2, troop3 = @troop3, hero = @hero) WHERE username = 'ryan'"`

Comment: @user3491814 What is the error message exactly? Can you write it as a full message? Are you using `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection`, right?

Answer (score 0):

and you can try this:

```
string query=string.format("UPDATE army SET troop1 = '{0}', troop2 = '{1}', troop3 ='{2}', hero = '{3}' WHERE username = 'ryan'",value0,value1,value2,value3);
```